# Identifying which iOS app caused the notification sound to play

Tags: ios, notifications

I often hear the notification bell go off in my iPhone, but when I pull down the drop-down of alert events, I dont see anything which matches the time the alert went off. Is there a way to see what event caused the alert notification to go off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the settings, go to **Notifications**, and select **Notification Center** for every app with **Sound** selected.

Then chose to **Sort Apps** by time.

That way, when you hear the sound, just access your **Notification Center**, and the culprit app will be on top.

Comment: If Notification Center is the pull-down from the top of the screen, this did not work for me. Lots of background notification sounds, but last notification events in the center are from yesterday. Weird. iOS 10.3.2